# Magento 2 sort by Attribute value

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, filter, sort

I have `multi-select` attribute name location like : Delhi , Maharashtra, Karnataka.

I want to use sort by of filter by in such way when I use above filter / sort it should show all products but product with matching attributes should show on top.

for example if I am using filter/sort with value as **Maharashtra** all products should show on listing page but products with value Maharashtra will be on top .

I can not find any way to do same please help with it how can it be done.

Comment: Have you created attribute ?

Comment: yes we have created attribute

Comment: just like position, name and price work ?

Comment: @Pawan can u help with issue

Comment: will try, do you want same as position and name work in sort option ?

Comment: yes  but i want to give values , something like ORDER BY FIELD  will work

Comment: please check my answer, if have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to override listing page product collection block. Separately get collection of products base on location, then append both collections.**

Answer (score -1):

Create New Product Attribute: 
In the tab: Properties
Default Label: Location
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Dropdown OR Multiple Select
Values:add your location

Storefront properties:
Use in Layered Navigation: Filterable(with result)

After assign this attribute to product set and run: php bin/magento c:f

Finally in category page showing.

Comment: please read my question is bit different